# How to implement regular expressions for the user

Tags: regex, code-snippets

I have an input field and filter based upon the users input, then can find all table cells that have a certain value.  Example: "50" will hide every row except the ones that have a table cell not equal to 50.

snippet:

```
var searchVal = $('#search').val();
$('tbody tr').each(function(index, row) {
   var myText = $(row).children('td:eq(3)').text();
   if (myText != searchVal) {
      $(row).hide();
   }
});
```

Q: How could I add pattern matching, or regular expression to my searching?  For example, I want to give my users the ability to type ">50" to find all table cells with a value of greater than 50.

Comment: Do you mean you want the user to be able to type a regular expression, or did you just mean that there might be a regular expression behind the scenes? remus thinks the former, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this:

```
var searchVal = $.trim($('#search').val());
var res = searchVal.match(/^[<>]?\d+$/);
if (res !== null) {
        var myText = $(row).children('td:eq(3)').text();
        if (res[0].charAt(0) === '<') {
            if (res[0].substr(1) < myText) {
                // handle case for less than #
            }
        } else if (res[0].charAt(0) === '>') {
            if (res[0].substr(1) > myText) {
                // handle case for greater than #
            }
        } else if (myText === res[0]) {
            // handle case for equal to # (ie. no symbol given in string)
        } else {
            // handle case for not equal to # (ie. no symbol given in string)
            $(row).hide();
        }
} else {
    // handle case where user input does not match
}
```

Comment: This of course breaks if `res[0].substr(1)` isn't an integer ;)

Comment: The RegEx match ensures that never happens first of all via the check: `if (res !== null)`.

Comment: oi! missed that completely. Ignore me :)

Answer (score 1):

`>50` is not a regular expression. You would need to compare numerical values with mathematical operators, although you could test for this possibility using regular expressions using something like this:

```
//if searchVal matches greater/less than and at least one number:
var searchVal = $('#search').val();
var matches = searchVal.match(/^([<>])(\d+)$/);
if (matches[1] == "<") {
    $('tbody tr').each(function(index, row) {
        var myText = $(row).children('td:eq(3)').text();
        if (myText >= parseInt(matches[2]))
           $(row).hide();
    });
}
else if (matches[1] == ">") {
    $('tbody tr').each(function(index, row) {
        var myText = $(row).children('td:eq(3)').text();
        if (myText <= parseInt(matches[2]))
           $(row).hide();
    });
}
```

However if you *do* want to use actual regular expressions, you could use Javascript's [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
var searchVal = $('#search').val();
var re = new RegExp(searchVal);
$('tbody tr').each(function(index, row) {
   var myText = $(row).children('td:eq(3)').text();
   if (re.test(myText)) {
      $(row).hide();
   }
});
```